# Symfony2 best practices for form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'd like to know if in Symfony2 **apart from the default csrf hidden field you would add other securities  in your forms for an average website**.

I assume forms are made with the formbuilder and no captcha is shown to the user by default.

I took some advices from 
http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html
and
https://www.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_implement_a_SPAM_control_countermeasure_that_remains_accessible_using_the_Stanford_Web_Application_Toolkit

1) Would you add an hidden field which has for value `base64_decode & base64_encode` on timestamp/datetime + salt?

Hence, you could limit the time bracket to send the form between [ 3 seconds ; 1 day ] with a validation constraint.

This would annoy both playback bots and form filling bots

2) Would you add a text field that you hide with CSS (honeypot) in order for bots to fill it when submitting the form? Then create a validation constraint so that if the field is not empty the form submission is not valid (and maybe log in your database ip and user agent if further actions are required).

This would annoy form filling bots.

3) Randomize fields names and ids so that playback bots could not send forms without reloading the website page. (though I have not yet tested if random names brings problems with the form builder)

This would annoy playback bots.

4) Any other idea?

Comment: Since bot can simulate browser interface interaction and mouse click, hidding fields will be useless. Changing name/id will also be useless since they can use className and index... Have a look to Catcha for Symfony

Comment: So Methods 2 and 3 are not that useful. I don't like captcha for user experience ; I'd prefer to log when forms are sent and then show a captcha if the forms has been sent more than x times in the past y seconds.

Comment: I agree, Captcha are pain... Solution 3 can be an option if you randomize id AND css class name AND ramdomize form place (to change indexes) but it won't block a dedicated robot to your site

Answer (score 0):

I used recently access_control from the app/config/security.yml file. There you can restrict acces to a path where you form lives in, using a role (you can use the default/anonymous role or you can define your own) and a channel (http or https)